# Ignore \n when text mining in R

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

### Introduction

I am trying to populate a data table from a large string that I acquired via webscraping. I intended to break the large chunk of text down to smaller bits, using a certain pattern as a reference. From these smaller bits I would create the variables that would go into the columns of the data table. Just to give you some context: I would like to learn how the members of the lower house of the Brazilian Congress voted when each bill was appreciated.

### Sample result

Each part was supposed to look like this:

SESSÃO ORDINÁRIA Nº 008 - 10/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPresente <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint"> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint" align="center">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t---\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://www.camara.leg.br/sileg/Prop_Lista.asp?Sigla=PL&Numero=7735&Ano=2014"> PL   Nº 7735/2014\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t - DVS - PRB - EMENDA Nº 193\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSim            \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr class="even">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t10/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t

Just so you can understand the pattern I'm about to show you and that I used in order to pass str_extract_all, the big string continues like this:

SESSÃO EXTRAORDINÁRIA Nº 009 - 10/02/2015\n ...

### Method

The code was supposed to extract the text between two "SESSÃO"'s using str_extract_all(html, "SESSÃO.*?(?=SESSÃO)") (html is the large string). However, if I used the code precisely like that, R would return an empty list.

I know that line breaks (\n) are causing the problem, because I was able to reach a very similar result as shown above by deleting the \n's from the main text applying str_replace_all to html, with "\n" as the pattern and "" as the replacement. I then called the result html1 and ran str_extract with x = html1 instead of x = html and the same pattern.

### Question

So my question is: can I tell str_extract_all to ignore \n? If not, is there another way I can treat this problem? I didn't want to delete the \n's, since they may come in handy when breaking down further the smaller bits of string.

### Additional sample string

As requested by andrew_reece, this is an expanded version of the sample string:

SESSÃO ORDINÁRIA Nº 008 - 10/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPresente <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint"> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint" align="center">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t---\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://www.camara.leg.br/sileg/Prop_Lista.asp?Sigla=PL&Numero=7735&Ano=2014"> PL   Nº 7735/2014\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t - DVS - PRB - EMENDA Nº 193\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSim            \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr class="even">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t10/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSESSÃO EXTRAORDINÁRIA Nº 009 - 10/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPresente <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint"> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint" align="center">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t---\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://www.camara.leg.br/sileg/Prop_Lista.asp?Sigla=PEC&Numero=358&Ano=2013"> PEC  Nº 358/2013\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t - PROPOSTA DE EMENDA À CONSTITUIÇÃO - 2º TURNO\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSim            \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://www.camara.leg.br/sileg/Prop_Lista.asp?Sigla=PEC&Numero=358&Ano=2013"> PEC  Nº 358/2013\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t - DVS - PSOL - ART. 2º DA PEC Nº 358/2013 - 2º TURNO\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSim            \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr class="even">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t11/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t

### Desired result

List with the following elements:

[1]

SESSÃO ORDINÁRIA Nº 008 - 10/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPresente <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint"> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint" align="center">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t---\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://www.camara.leg.br/sileg/Prop_Lista.asp?Sigla=PL&Numero=7735&Ano=2014"> PL   Nº 7735/2014\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t - DVS - PRB - EMENDA Nº 193\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSim            \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr class="even">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t10/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t

[2]

SESSÃO EXTRAORDINÁRIA Nº 009 - 10/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPresente <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint"> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint" align="center">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t---\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://www.camara.leg.br/sileg/Prop_Lista.asp?Sigla=PEC&Numero=358&Ano=2013"> PEC  Nº 358/2013\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t - PROPOSTA DE EMENDA À CONSTITUIÇÃO - 2º TURNO\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSim            \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href="http://www.camara.leg.br/sileg/Prop_Lista.asp?Sigla=PEC&Numero=358&Ano=2013"> PEC  Nº 358/2013\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t - DVS - PSOL - ART. 2º DA PEC Nº 358/2013 - 2º TURNO\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  <sup style="font-size:10px">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSim            \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr class="even">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t11/02/2015\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="borderPrint">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t

Comment: .* will return an empty list because it doesn't consider \n

Comment: Please provide a full example string (including the second SESSAO matching part), and expected output from your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Without example data, this is not tested, but I believe that what you need is

```
str_extract_all(html, regex("SESSÃO.*?(?=SESSÃO|$)", dotall = TRUE))
```

Note that I added `|$` so that it will detect the last group in your data, but the main point is to include `dotall = TRUE`